# Oracle query data base on TIME without show it to result

Tags: oracle

I'm using `Oracle 11g`.

I would like to sort my data based on `TIME ASC` but I don't want `TIME` show on result.

Query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
D.DESCRIPTION,
D.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS,
Y.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS2,
Y.TIME
FROM 
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D
LEFT OUTER JOIN WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
WHERE
D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0002' AND
D.ACTIVE = 'Y'
ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC
```

If I remove `Y.TIME`, it show me error

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

Is there any way how to keep sort by `Y.TIME` without `Y.TIME` show on result?

Let see on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf326/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with ordering by `TIME` while not selecting it is due to that you are doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` query.  In the result set, there will only be one record for each combination of `D.DESCRIPTIONID`, `D.DESCRIPTION`, `D.PROFILEID_FK`, and `Y.PROFILEID_FK`.  If you `ORDER BY` the time without selecting it, the question now is *which* value of time would you like to use when ordering each potential *group* of records which generates each single record in the result set?  This is not clear, so Oracle will not proceed with such a query.

Here is an alternative query which should work:

```
SELECT
    D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
    D.DESCRIPTION,
    D.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS,
    Y.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS2
FROM WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D
LEFT OUTER JOIN WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y
    ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
WHERE
    D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0002' AND
    D.ACTIVE = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
    D.DESCRIPTION,
    D.PROFILEID_FK,
    Y.PROFILEID_FK
ORDER BY
    MAX(Y.TIME);
```

Here I have rewritten the distinct query as a group by query, and it is logically identical to what you originally had.  But now I `ORDER BY` an *aggregate* of the time, in this case the maximum value.  Now there is no ambiguity as to what you mean when ordering by the time.

Note that many RDBMS will implement a distinct query under the hood using group by.

Comment: I tried your code, and remove comma after Y.PROFILEID_FK  and still got error: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Apologies...I had a typo and was still doing `SELECT DISTINCT`.  The query should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to bury Y.TIME in a subquery, then just don't pull that field in the outer query:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTIONID, 
       DESCRIPTION,
       PROFILEID_FKS,
       PROFILEID_FKS2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
                        D.DESCRIPTION,
                        D.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS,
                        Y.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS2,
                        Y.TIME
          FROM WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D
          LEFT OUTER JOIN WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y
            ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
          WHERE D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0002' AND
                D.ACTIVE = 'Y'
          ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC)
```

If you want to be fancier you can put the subquery into a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cteDESC AS (SELECT DISTINCT D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
                                 D.DESCRIPTION,
                                 D.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS,
                                 Y.PROFILEID_FK AS PROFILEID_FKS2,
                                 Y.TIME
                   FROM WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y
                     ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
                   WHERE D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0002' AND
                         D.ACTIVE = 'Y'
                   ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC)
SELECT DESCRIPTIONID, 
       DESCRIPTION,
       PROFILEID_FKS,
       PROFILEID_FKS2
  FROM cteDESC;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: But how can you guarantee the ordering of the outer query without using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hi Bob, tried your code but the ordering by time is not correct.

Comment: Move the ORDER BY clause to the outer query (ORDER BY TIME).